# modules exist, pyCharm suggest me the name, but import fails

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new in python and I'm facing with some problems with module/packages and import. I have a python project in pyCharm, this is my project's structure:

```
project 
   |
   |------ model (package)
             |
             |---- __init__.py
             |---- impianto.py
             |---- componente.py
             |---- sorgente.py
   |------- app.py
```

every module defines a class with the same name, so impianto.py defines a class called Impianto, componente.py defines a class called Componente and so on. In app.py I have an import for the Impianto class. This is what I do:

```
from model.impianto import Impianto
```

in impianto.py I import Componente like this:

```
from model.componente import Componente
```

and in componente.py I import Sorgente like this:

```
from model.sorgente import Sorgente
```

please note that Sorgente extends Componente and pyCharm suggested me the import names, but when I run app.py it gives me this error

```
  File "/home/gjcode/PycharmProjects/es3_2016/app.py", line 2, in 
  <module>
  from model.impianto import Impianto
  File "/home/gjcode/PycharmProjects/es3_2016/model/impianto.py", line 1, in <module>
from model.componente import Componente
File "/home/gjcode/PycharmProjects/es3_2016/model/componente.py", line 1, in <module>
from model.sorgente import Sorgente
File "/home/gjcode/PycharmProjects/es3_2016/model/sorgente.py", line 1, in <module>
from model.componente import Componente
ImportError: cannot import name 'Componente'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have circular dependent imports. you try to execute

```
from model.componente import Componente
```

in two files, in `sorgente.py` and in `impianto.py` try to remove from `sogrente.py`

```
from model.componente import Componente
```

Comment: I removed: from model.sorgente import Sorgente and it works, but I need Sorgente class in Componente class. I had read something on this topic and now I know how imports work. I putted the import statement of sorgente at the bottom of Componente class and it seems to work. It is a good practise?